# Android sharing files by sending them via other apps

Tags: android

I have to share files in my android app by sending them via email or any other sharing app. I have written code inside a static ViewHolder class in Adapter class but getting below exception-
[image]

**Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?**

I set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to intent also, but still getting same exception.

```
private void shareFile(File file) {

Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intentShareFile.setType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName()));
            Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);

            intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Send to"));
}
```

Comment: Make `context` be an `Activity` and get rid of `getApplicationContext()`. Also bear in mind that you will crash with a `FileUriExposedException` -- please use `FileProvider`, not `Uri.parse()`, to create the `Uri`. You will also need to add `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to allow the other app to use your `Uri`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content).

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, with your solution the exception is resolved but instead of showing applications it showing No apps can perform this action. I have added modified code and screen shot in edit.

Comment: You do not need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` now. Beyond that, you should check Logcat or otherwise determine what you are setting for the MIME type.